# Weird psql behavior during insert, when table name ends with 0

Tags: postgresql, insert

I'm experiencing an insert failure. To be precise, it not causing an error, but it just freezes and doesn't do anything when I run the following code:

```
INSERT INTO public.table_0 VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -999.25);
```

Note how the table name I am inserting to ends with `0`. However, if I insert to a different table whose name does not end with digit `0`, insert works perfectly.

```
INSERT INTO public.table_50 VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -999.25);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: if this cannot be replicated there isn't much we can do. what freezes? what version of postgres? do you have more then one environment? can you replicate it? why don't you specify the columns names when inserting? too many unknowns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely there is something that is holding a lock on `public.table_0` that blocks your insert.

You can identify a blocking lock with a query like this:

```
SELECT locktype, relation, transactionid, pid, mode
FROM pg_locks WHERE NOT granted;

   locktype    | relation | transactionid | pid  |   mode    
---------------+----------+---------------+------+-----------
 transactionid |          |          4125 | 4434 | ShareLock
(1 row)
```

Then on recent PostgreSQL versions you can see who is blocking that backend:

```
SELECT pg_blocking_pids(4434);

 pg_blocking_pids 
------------------
 {4589}
(1 row)
```

And you should find a statement that is active or idle in transaction:

```
SELECT datname, usename, application_name, xact_start, state
FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid = 4589;

 datname | usename | application_name |          xact_start           |        state        
---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------
 test    | laurenz | psql             | 2018-10-25 07:03:13.112879+02 | idle in transaction
(1 row)
```